# Erro ao gravar caracteres especiais

Tags: adobe-flex

Bom dia, estou com um problema, trabalho com flex e java, tenho uma parte no sistema em que gravo texto, eu consigo gravar qualquer coisa, porem ao tentar gravar caracter especial tipo º ª ° ¬, o sistema me traz um erro de Format specifier 's'. Alguem sabe o que pode ser? Obrigado.